# Sending packets to lighttpd server

Tags: c, tcp, lighttpd, packets

I have installed the `lighttpd server` on to my computer.

I am current writing C code on my computer where I am sending *packets* to the `lighttpd server`.

How do I establish that connection with the server in the code I am writing?

Comment: I think you're asking "how do I write networking code in C?".  [Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) is a great place to start for this.

Comment: You can listen in ligthttpd server on port on which you want to connect the client.

Comment: Applications don't send packets over a TCP connection, they send *bytes*. TCP presents a byte stream to the application. Not keeping this straight will cause you a large amount of pain.

Comment: Thank you for all the advice I will look into it!